# Interpretation of int returned by XalanInitialize()?

Tags: xalan, xerces-c

I am using XALAN to transform from xsl to html,

following is the snippet of the code,

```
    //
    //  XALAN_USING_XERCES(XMLPlatformUtils), init namespace
    //
    XALAN_USING_XALAN(XalanTransformer)

    //
    //  2. Initialize Xalan and Xerces
    //
    iRet = XalanInitialize();
```

how should i use this `iRet` to handel error cases of XalanInitialize,,,

```
    //
    //  3. Create a Xalan transformer
    //
    hXalan = NULL;
    hXalan = CreateXalanTransformer();
    if (NULL == hXalan)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    //
    //  4. Perform transformation.
    //
    iRet = XalanTransformToFile(m_strPath.c_str(), strXslIn.c_str(), strHtmlOut.c_str(), hXalan);
    if (0 != iRet)
    {

        DeleteXalanTransformer(hXalan);
        XalanTerminate(false);
        return FALSE;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer in the source code,

0 if sucessful 
and -1 otherwise.

Can refer,

http://code.metager.de/source/xref/apache/xalan/c/src/xalanc/XalanTransformer/XalanCAPI.cpp#54